# Fill object from SQL result

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I have a regular C# class called "vehicle" with properties like Name, NumberPlate, MaxSpeed, etc.
All the data for the class is stored in a SQLite Database where I have a Table "Car" and "Boat". The tables colums have the same names as the class properties (however, there are more columns than class properties - vehicle is a more generic abstraction). At the moment, I have to assign the result of the query individually one by one like this:

```
while (await statement.StepAsync())
{
myVehicle.Name = statement.Columns["Name"];
//[...]
myVehicle.MaxSpeed = decimal.TryParse(statement.Columns["MaxSpeed"]);
}
```

Additionally, I have to check if some columns exist ("Car" and "Boat" have a different set of columns) which is more code than I'd like it to be.

I read about EntityFramework to map my db table to my class - but that seems overkill. My requirement is to map properties and columns that have the same name and ignore everything else.
Is there a "easy" (dev time, lines of code) way to map my table columns to my class?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Does EF even work on phone 8? I thought ADO.NET was completely missing...

Comment: @MarcGravell I think it is. See: http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/using-entity-framework-create

Comment: hmm; unsure how much of that is EF vs just using generated classes, but interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The restrictions in phone 8 mean that a lot of the *standard* answers to this ("just use {some ORM / micro-ORM}") won't apply, since they *don't work* on phone 8. You can probably use reflection for a lot of this, but: reflection can be (relatively) slow, so it depends on how much data you will be processing. If it is occasional and light: fine, reflect away.

Runtime meta-programming (the tricks used by libraries like "dapper" in full .NET to make these things really fast) is not available on restricted runtimes, so if you want to avoid lots of boiler-plate that leaves build-time meta-programming. At the simplest, I wonder if you could use something like T4 to automate creating these methods for you as C#. There *are* also ways to use the reflection-emit API to construct assemblies (at build-time) for phone 8, but that is a pretty hard-core route.

My thoughts:

- if the amount of types here isn't huge, just write the code
- if you have a *lot* of types, or you just feel like it, consider a build-time code-generation meta-programming step; you might even think "hmm, is this something I could make available to the community?"

  - of course, the first thing to do is to check that such a thing *doesn't already exist*

Comment: I found AutoMapper - will try if this does the job for me. Still leaving this question open for the case there is a magic bullet for my scenario (WP8, SQLite, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

There is a little **[helper](http://trikks.wordpress.com/2012/12/31/mapping-dictionary-to-typed-object-using-c/)** which might fit your case. Basically, it will take a dictionary and try it's best to populate a objects properties using reflection. I didn't try it by myself though.

You'd simply do something like:

```
while (await statement.StepAsync())
{
    myVehicle = DictionaryToObject<Car>(statement.Columns);
}
```

It might need some further work to get it running but maybe a good start.